# how to get go mod tidy not try to download local packages

Tags: go, bazel, skaffold

I have a go monorepo with a few packages that at one point had an import path like `github.com/user/ticketing/tickets/models/connection`, but is a private repo and I'd rather not have to depend on the remote repo anyway for deployment on kubernetes/skaffold. I was wondering how when running `go mod tidy`, I can prevent tidy from trying to download the local packages but instead have everything point to the local packages instead through masking/shadowing. I'm open to a bazel-based solution as well, but I feel like tidy would not be impacted by anything around bazel. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to depend on the availability of a remote repository the usual practice it to do vendoring of the dependencies. Similar questions have already been asked: [what is the purpose of `go mod vendor` command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544611/what-is-the-purpose-of-go-mod-vendor-command)