# Do we commit vendor folder changes?

Tags: go

I want to know about vendor folder in a Go project.

I cloned a go repo and made my code changes.
But when I try to run the related test I got some error messages. On some google search, I found that I need to run some commands:

- go mod tidy
- go mod vendor

Now issues are gone, but I see a large number of files in vendor folder have changed.

Is it acceptable?

Do I need to commit all these file?

Comment: The reason to use `vendor/` is to commit the files. If you don’t want to do that, then you don’t need `vendor`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`vendor` folder contains all dependencies of the project so it usually is not committed to the repository.

You should however commit `go.mod` and `go.sum` files, if there is nothing sketchy with libs you depend on (removing version, sources etc), `vendor` folder should be fully reproducible from the `go.sum` file.

With Go modules `vendor` folder is rarely used tho. Most people do not use it locally either. Running `go mod download` instead of `go mod vendor` would download modules to a modules directory on your system (by default $GOPATH/pkg).

You can read more about vendoring with [Go modules in docs.](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vendoring) Or checkout the whole Go modules documentation https://go.dev/ref/mod.

Comment: The only purpose of censoring is to commit the vendord stuff and be able to work offline. If vendoring then commit. Just don’t vendor.

Comment: If you’re not going to commit the vendor directory, then there is no point of using it at all. The purpose of having it is to commit the files.

Comment: s/censoring/vendoring/ (stupid auto correction).

Comment: `vendor folder is rarely used tho.` - not true. There are very legitimate reasons to use `go mod vendor` as [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544611/what-is-the-purpose-of-go-mod-vendor-command).